Batch script - cant split a txt file into two txt's when a word occurs
I'm currently struggling with a batch script. I'm not sure where the bug is, but here is my code. I want to create two text files whenever the word "VALUES" appears. However, every time I try to make some changes, it still doesn't work properly.
Below, I am including the code, a few lines of the text file that I want to split, and the expected results.
My code:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "input_file=SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=SQL-FILES\part2.txt"

:: Ensure the output files are empty before starting
> %part1_file% echo(
> %part2_file% echo(

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%input_file%) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=VALUES" %%B in ("%%A") do (
        echo %%B >> %part1_file%
        if "%%C" neq "" (
            echo VALUES%%C >> %part2_file%
        )
    )
)

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause

I tried multiple ways, even asked GPT to help me solve this problem but it still doesn't work.
My .TXT file includes:
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (3,2,2,NULL,Data ważności (FEFO),NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (4,2,3,NULL,Data dostawy (FIFO),NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (7,6,1,NULL,Возгараемые,NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (8,4,1,NULL,Kartony TYP A,NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (9,4,2,NULL,Pojemniki,NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (11,5,1,NULL,Kartony,NULL,0,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id,DictCatId,Value,TextCode,ShortDesc,LongDesc,Sys,Hide,Color) VALUES (12,5,2,NULL,Pojemniki,NULL,0,0,NULL);

As you can see its just SQL inserts and I want to make 2 txt files as described higher.
part1.txt must include only:
INSERT INTO dbo.Dict (id, DictCatId, Value, TextCode, ShortDesc, LongDesc, Sys, Hide, Color) VALUES

part2.txt must include:
(3, 2, 2, NULL, Data ważności (FEFO), NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

EDIT:
I just figured it out; here is what I changed in the for loop:
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%input_file%" ^| findstr /r /c:"VALUES "') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    echo Processing line: !line!
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=)" %%B in ("!line!") do (
        set "first_part=%%B)"
        set "second_part=%%C"
        set "second_part=!second_part: VALUES =!"
        echo !first_part! VALUES >> %part1_file%
        echo !second_part! >> %part2_file%
    )
)


Do you know what delimiters are? they are individual characters, not whole words. Every line parsed will be split at, the location of each one of theose choracters.

I suggest the following command lines for the batch file:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "input_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part2.txt"

rem Ensure the output files do not exist before starting.
del /A /F "%part1_file%" "%part2_file%" 2>nul 

(for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%input_file%") do (
    set "Line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=^|^ eol^= %%G in ("!Line: VALUES =|!") do (
        endlocal
        echo(%%G VALUES
        if not "%%H" == "" echo(%%H>>"%part2_file%"
    )
))>"%part1_file%"

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause

The UTF-8 without BOM encoded input file dbo.Dict.txt is expected in the subdirectory SQL-FILES in the directory containing the batch file instead of the current working directory which can be any directory on using this code.
The two output files are first deleted which is necessary only for part2.txt but not for part1.txt which is created new. However, the usage of command DEL with the options /A and /F forces a deletion of existing output files even on having hidden and/or read-only attribute set.
The Windows Command Processor creates new now first the output file part1.txt and keeps that file open for appending everything output by the first ECHO command line during processing of the non-empty lines in the input file.
The first FOR /F loop processes the non-empty lines in the input file. The usage of the options usebackq delims= eol= results in interpreting the double quoted string as file name of the file of which lines must be processed by FOR with an empty list of delimiters to disable the default line splitting behavior on normal spaces and horizontal tabs and no end of line character for not ignoring lines beginning with a semicolon. The options are not enclosed in " as usual as that is the only method to specify an empty list of delimiters and no end of line character. The missing double quotes require escaping normal space and equal sign with ^ for being interpreted as part of the not quoted options string and not as argument string separators.
Each non-empty line is assigned to the environment variable Line while delayed variable expansion is disabled. That makes it possible processing also lines in the input file containing one or more exclamation marks. If delayed variable expansion is enabled already above the FOR /F loop and the three file names are referenced with ! instead of % and the setlocal and endlocal commands are removed inside the loop, the processing of the lines would be faster but would produce the wrong result on any line in the input file contains one or more exclamation marks.
It is necessary to enable delayed variable expansion to access the line string assigned to the environment variable Line which is the reason for enabling it now. Read this answer for details about the commands SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL and what happens on each execution of these two commands in background.
A string substitution is used which replaces case-insensitive all occurrences of VALUES with a space before and a space after by the single delimiter character |. That character should not exist anywhere left to VALUES and also not immediately after the space character after VALUES. There should be also not multiple VALUES with a space before and after this string on a line on using this code. Another never existing character must be used in case of | could be also in the input file left to space delimited VALUES.
The resulting line string with | as delimiter between the two parts of interest is split up with one more FOR /F loop using | as delimiter which must be escaped with ^ as being otherwise interpreted as redirection operator in the options string not enclosed in " for the same reason as before.
There is restored first the previous environment with disabled delayed variable expansion before the string left to VALUES is output first which is written into the permanently opened first output file.
If there is a second string after delimiter |, it is also output with opening the second output file, seeking to end of the file, appending the string without a trailing space because of no space left to redirection operator >>, and closing the file. That write operations to second file are less efficient in comparison to the write operations to first file because of the file cannot be opened all the time for each line to append.
I recommend reading:

Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files
It explains why the syntax not "…" == "…" should be used for comparing to strings on inequality and not the integer comparison operator NEQ.
Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?
It explains why care must be taken where a space character is used on a command line which uses the command ECHO with a redirection operator like > or >> for writing the output into a file.

Faster is the following code which can be used only if no line in input file contains ever an exclamation mark.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "input_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part2.txt"

rem Ensure the output files do not exist before starting.
del "%part1_file%" "%part2_file%" 2>nul 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!input_file!") do (
    set "Line=%%L"
    for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=^|^ eol^= %%G in ("!Line: VALUES =|!") do (
        echo(%%G VALUES
        if not "%%~H" == "" echo(%%H>>"!part2_file!"
    )
))>"!part1_file!"
endlocal

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause

If the input file can contain also other lines not containing the string VALUES delimited by normal spaces which should be completely ignored, it would be better using:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "input_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part2.txt"

rem Ensure the output files do not exist before starting.
del "%part1_file%" "%part2_file%" 2>nul 

(for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:" VALUES " "%input_file%"') do (
    set "Line=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=^|^ eol^= %%G in ("!Line: VALUES =|!") do (
        endlocal
        echo(%%G VALUES
        if not "%%~H" == "" >>"%part2_file%" echo(%%H
    )
))>"%part1_file%"

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause

The command FINDSTR executed in background by starting one more command process with %ComSpec% /c and the specified command line between ' in the first FOR /F command line is used in this case as line filter which searches case-sensitive for lines containing literally the string VALUES with a space before and after this word. The output of FINDSTR to handle STDOUT (standard output) of the background command process is captured by the command process processing the batch file and processed next by FOR as described above.
There is one more solution which opens both output files at once before opening the input file. The code below demonstrates that solution with usage of FINDSTR as lines filter and permanently enabled delayed expansion for best performance as long as no line in input file contains an exclamation mark.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "input_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=%~dp0SQL-FILES\part2.txt"
if not exist "%input_file%" exit /B

rem Ensure the output files do not exist before starting.
del "%part1_file%" "%part2_file%" 2>nul 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:" VALUES " "!input_file!" 2^>nul') do (
    set "Line=%%L"
    for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=^|^ eol^= %%G in ("!Line: VALUES =|!") do (
        echo(%%G VALUES
        if not "%%~H" == "" 1>&2 echo(%%H
    )
))>"!part1_file!" 2>"!part2_file!"
endlocal

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause

The output of the second ECHO to handle STDOUT is redirected to handle STDERR (standard error) which is redirected into the second output file opened just once before starting the FOR loop and closed finally after the FOR loop finished the processing. The redirection operator 1>&2 is left to ECHO command for avoiding a trailing space in second output file on each line output by the second ECHO command in the inner FOR loop.
There is an additional IF condition for checking the existing of the input file before doing any file operation and the error output of FINDSTR in case of input file cannot be opened at all for whatever reason is suppressed by redirecting it to the device NUL to avoid writing this error output into the second output file.

A different, simpler approach:
@echo off
setlocal

set "input_file=SQL-FILES\dbo.Dict.txt"
set "part1_file=SQL-FILES\part1.txt"
set "part2_file=SQL-FILES\part2.txt"

rem Enable Unicode Code Page to manage extended UTF-8 characters
chcp 65001 > NUL

rem For each line, call :split subroutine
rem Redirect Stdout output to first file and Stderr output to second file
( for /F "delims=" %%A in (input_file) do call :split "%%A" ) > "%part1_file%" 2> "%part2_file%"

echo File split complete.
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF


:split
set "line=%~1"
echo %line: VALUES= VALUES& >&2 echo% 
exit /B

The code is simple enough to understand it with no further explanations. The interesting part happen at the echo command in :split subroutine: divide the line at the VALUES word inserting an additional echo command that will echo the rest of the line to Stderr (file handle number 2).
If you want to check that the part2 not be empty (as in your code), change the echo command by this one:
echo %line: VALUES= VALUES&set "part2=%"

... and then you can test for the value of %part2%
